# Extracting from lists of pandas series to another based on indexes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have  pandas data frame having 2 series each of them contains 2d arrays like,
a is the first series sub-array is of different length like

```
a: 
0 [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7],[1,2,3,4,5],[5,9,3,2]]
1 [[1,2,3],[6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

and b is the second one but its subarray has only one element like

```
b:
 0 [[0],[2],[3]]
 1 [ [1],[0],[1]]
```

I want to extract elements of the a series based on indexes given in b.
The result of the above example should be like:

```
0 [1,3,2]
1 [2, 6, 9]
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot

Comment: you should post the dataframe rather than series

Comment: accounts                                                             indexes
0  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7], [1, 2, 3], [6, 7],[8,9,10]]       [[3], [0], [0], [2]]
1  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7], [1, 2, 3]]                              [[4], [1]]
2  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]]                                            [[2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
a = pd.Series({0: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 9, 3, 2]],
               1: [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]})

b = pd.Series({0: [[0], [2], [3]], 1: [[1], [0], [1]]})
```

---

Difficult to make this efficient since you have lists of varying sizes, but here's a solution using a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
out = pd.Series([[x[y] for x, [y] in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(a, b)])
```

```
0    [1, 3, 2]
1    [2, 6, 9]
dtype: object
```

Comment: That solution is so much prettier than my idea that I could cry! Nice work.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it gives me IndexError: Invalid index to scalar variable

Comment: Then the example you've provided doesn't accurately represent your data.  Make sure your columns are actually lists and not strings, but this code works using the setup data I provided

Comment: Again thanks a bunch for the help. Inside array are numpy arrays, any idea what to do please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to index `a` with `b`:

```
df.apply(lambda row: [row.a[i][row.b[i][0]] for i in range(len(row[0]))], axis=1)   
0    [1, 3, 2]
1    [2, 6, 9]
dtype: object
```

Data:

```
data = {"a":[[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7],[1,2,3,4,5],[5,9,3,2]],
             [[1,2,3],[6,7],[8,9,10]]],
        "b": [[[0],[2],[3]], 
              [[1],[0],[1]]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```